# How can I export everything from a third party JavaScript library in my own library?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm wrapping a third party JS library with my own TS code. Up until know I've been importing and exporting components ad-hoc.

**index.ts:**

```
import { Button } from 'third-party'

export { Button }
```

Can I just export everything from the library? I tried `export * from 'third-party'` but this didn't work.

**EDIT** 
The error I'm seeing is

```
Module ... has no exported member ...
```

Comment: Check whether the library is listed at Definitely Typed https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

Comment: export * from 'third-party'. yes you can do this. what error you have?

Comment: @QuentinUK it's a private internal library

Comment: @JurajKocan I've updated the question with the error

Comment: this error is when you type "export * from 'third-party'"??.

Comment: the error is when I try importing, `import {Button} from 'my-lib'` where *my-lib* includes the `export * from 'third-party'`

Comment: third-party is pure js? does it have d.ts? it looks that only ts dont know that this export is there. in runtime it should be ok

Answer (score 3):

You could try export using a `namespace`

```
export * as utils from 'third-party'
```